# Patch a function call within function from different file using Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am currently learning how to perform unit test in Python.

I have a file `app/utils/B.py` that is imported by file `app/views/A.py`
`B.py` imports function from `app/utils/util.py`.

**B.py**

```py
from app.utils.util import log_error

def do_something():
    try:
        int(10/0)
    except Exception as e:
        log_error({"msg": "error"})
```

**A.py**

```py
from app.utils.B import do_something

def calculation():
   do_something()
```

My question is, when writing the test for A, I tried to see if `log_error` works.
I tried `@patch("app.views.A.log_error", autospec=True)` but this mock doesn't been called.

Could anyone suggest a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you patch `B.log_error` instead? As far as I can see, there is no `A.log_error`.

Comment: Yes, I found this out and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the answer myself, path module B instead

```py
@patch("app.utils.B.log_eror", autospec=True)
```